# How to take photo from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-camera

I want to take photo from fragment but if I use follow codes **onActivityResult Intent data** **return** **null**. I didn't figure out why **Intent data return null**?

CameraFragement.java

```
private void takePictureIntent() {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}

String imagePath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    imagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  { // this Intent data return null
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
        intent.setData(data.getData());
        startActivity(intent);

    } 
}
```

If I use this follow code instead of above **takePictureIntent** **Intent data return with extras** but **data.getData() return null**. I don't want to return data with extras. I don't want to Bitmap data. I need datas Uri form. I need **data.getData()**. This follow code used to before but now it's not work. I update my application always with Android SDK. I think this is the reason but what is the solution?

```
private void takePictureIntent() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

**Edit:** I tried almost everything but **Intent data still return null**. I am using follow code with first code example for now. You can use this, it's works fine. If you have a solution for Intent data please don't forget to notice me.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostActivity.class);
        intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate, why did you add `firebase` tag to this question (intentionally)? Because I don't see any usage of it there

Answer (score 2):

//capture image

```
public void requestTakePhoto() {
 //SettingsManager.sharedInstance().TAKE_PHOTO = true;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
  final File photoFile;
  try {
    photoFile = createImageFile();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    // Error occurred while creating the File
    Log.e("ChatActivity", "Unable to create photo file", e);
    return;
  }
  // Continue only if the File was successfully created
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_TAKE_PHOTO);
  }
}
```

//save captured image

```
private Uri mPhotoLocation;
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
  final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(newDate());
  final String imageFileName = timeStamp + "filename";
  final File storageDir =     Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  final File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
  mPhotoLocation = Uri.fromFile(image);
  return image;
}
```

//handle result

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

 switch (requestCode) {
  case REQ_PICK_IMAGE:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {

      Uri  uri =data.getData();

      //do your work with data

     // String filePath = getRealPathFromUri(uri);
      //if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
       // Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        //sendImageMessage(fileUri);
      }
    }
    break;
  case REQ_TAKE_PHOTO:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
      //do your work with data
      String filePath = getRealPathFromUri(mPhotoLocation);
      if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        sendImageMessage(fileUri);
      }
      mPhotoLocation = null;
    }
    break;
  case REQ_FILE_ATTACHMENT:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null) {
      Uri uri = data.getData();
      //String filePath = getRealPathFromUri(uri);
      //if (filePath != null && !filePath.isEmpty()) {
        //Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        //sendFileMessage(fileUri);
      }
    }
    break;
  default:
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    break;
  }
}
```

//get realpath

```
public String getRealPathFromUri(final Uri uri) {
// DocumentProvider
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(getActivity(), uri)) {
  // ExternalStorageProvider
   if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
    final String type = split[0];

    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
      return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
    }
  }
  // DownloadsProvider
  else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
      Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

    return getDataColumn(getActivity(), contentUri, null, null);
  }
  // MediaProvider
  else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
    final String type = split[0];

    Uri contentUri = null;
    if ("image".equals(type)) {
      contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
      contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
      contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    final String selection = "_id=?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
      split[1]
    };

    return getDataColumn(getActivity(), contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
  }
}
// MediaStore (and general)
else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

  // Return the remote address
  if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
    return uri.getLastPathSegment();

  return getDataColumn(getActivity(), uri, null, null);
}
// File
else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
  return uri.getPath();
}

 return null;
}


private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

Cursor cursor = null;
final String column = "_data";
final String[] projection = {
  column
};

try {
  cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
    null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
    return cursor.getString(index);
  }
} finally {
  if (cursor != null)
    cursor.close();
}
 return null;
 }

private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
   return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }

private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
  return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }

private boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
   return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
 }
```

Comment: thanks for help but this almost same my way and still Intent data return null. I updated my question and I wrote temporary answer to take help your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the requestcode is lost in the fragment, you need to use activity context:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: even I tried this;
getActivity().startActivityFromFragment(CameraFragment.this, intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
but nope. still doesn't work.

Comment: did you try setData(photoURI) in your takePictureIntent

Comment: I tried and I got this error;  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
I think we can't use setData with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.

Answer (score 0):

This library will help you to fetch image from `Camera` or `Storage` to view in `Activity` or `Fragment`.
Its provide very simple methods t do that,

https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library

Comment: I didn't want to use library for this issue. I think solution is easy but I missed something.

Comment: Yes, I know that is easy but check this library code, this will help you to findout your issue.

Comment: I checked that library. If use it I have to change my apps logic. I didn't want that for now.  I didn't vote down btw.